# Trying to understand how zip(*) iteration works in Python

Tags: python, python-zip

I'm a beginner in Python and trying my hand at using Leetcode & other online resources to learn Python! Recently saw this solution being passed around for longestCommonPrefix on leetcode (thank you hwendy12 !) and was a little curious as how zip(*list) works.

```
    def longestCommonPrefix(self, strs): 
    """
    :type strs: List[str]
    :rtype: str
    """
        answer = ''
        for i in zip(*strs):
            if len(set(i)) == 1:
                answer += i[0]
            else:
                break
        return answer
```

I tried searching around and it seems that the * 'unpacks' a list and makes each element a separate argument? I'm a little shaky on how zip works as well and so just wanted to ask what the difference between what zip(list) vs zip(*list) does and what each produces.

Thank you so much!

Comment: "zip(list) vs zip(*list)" - see the zip documentation. zip with one argument is useless

Comment: It's trivial to see for yourself what the results are in a Python shell. `list(zip(["hello", "world"]))` yields `[('hello',), ('world',)]` whereas unpacking `list(zip(*["hello", "world"]))` (which is equivalent to `list(zip("hello", "world"))`) will yield `[('h', 'w'), ('e', 'o'), ('l', 'r'), ('l', 'l'), ('o', 'd')]`.

Comment: Earlier posts is very helpful, you should read through.  If you just give one argument to zip, then you will still get `tuples` results:  >>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print(*zip(lst))
(1,) (2,) (3,) (4,)